# Compile dynamic regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Is it at all possible to dynamically generate a regular expression using values from an array in Perl?

Lets assume I have an array of keywords that I want to match on.  How can I build the regex from the values in that array?

The following doesn't seem to work

```
### Generate regex dynamically
my @regx_array = ('apples','oranges','bananas');
my $dynanic_regx = qr/join("|",@regx_array)/;
```

As I'm looking for the following regex:

```
(?^i:apples|oranges|bananas);
```

But instead I end up with

```
(?^i:join("|",ARRAY(0x34c5924)));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @regx_array = ('apples','oranges','bananas');
my ($dynamic_regx) = map qr/$_/i, join "|", map quotemeta, @regx_array;
```

Comment: Ask if additional explanation is required.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of things wrong.  First, you're building your array incorrectly.

```
my @regx_array = ['apples','oranges','bananas'];
```

You use parentheses to create a list.

```
my @regx_array = ('apples','oranges','bananas');
```

Then do this:

```
my $list = join( '|', @regx_array );
my $dynamic_regx = qr/$list/i;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just end up matching on a string containing "apples|oranges|bananas" rather than apples, oranges or bananas?

Comment: I stand corrected.  Works perfectly.  So simple. :)

Comment: parenthesis do not create a list.  they play a syntactic role only in a few limited cases.  in this code, they are only there because `,` is lower precedence than `=`

Answer (score 0):

Even easier than the other two:

```
my @regx_array = qw(apples oranges bananas);
local $" = '|';
my $regex      = qr/(@regx_array)/i;
```

`$"` is also known as the [**`$LIST_SEPARATOR`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR). And about that value:

> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string ... its elements are separated by this value. Default is a space.